# Terraform 11 to 12 Upgrade. ERROR: Unsupported attribute

Tags: terraform

I recently upgraded from Terraform 11 to 12 using the *terraform 0.12upgrade* command and now I'm getting the following error when I run a *terraform validate*:

```
$ ~/terraform/us-west-2/app/production/db/rds $  terraform validate

Error: Unsupported attribute

  on main.tf line 111, in resource "aws_rds_cluster" "app_db_production":
 111:   master_password                 = data.aws_kms_secret.app_db_production.master_password

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"master_password".

$ ~/terraform/us-west-2/app/production/db/rds $
```

The configuration in question:

```
data "aws_kms_secret" "app_db_production" {
  secret {
    name    = "master_password"
    payload = "2430db63c4f1479f122fb219d179afb1"
  }
}

resource "aws_rds_cluster" "app_db_production" {
  cluster_identifier              = "app-db-production"
  engine                          = "aurora-mysql"
  database_name                   = "app"
  port                            = 3306
  master_username                 = "root"
  master_password                 = data.aws_kms_secret.app_db_production.master_password
  backup_retention_period         = 7
  preferred_backup_window         = "02:00-03:00"
  preferred_maintenance_window    = "sat:03:00-sat:04:00"
  storage_encrypted               = true
  apply_immediately               = false
  final_snapshot_identifier       = "app-db-production-final-snapshot"
  db_cluster_parameter_group_name = "app-db-production"
  db_subnet_group_name            = "app-db-production"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [data.terraform_remote_state.app_production_db_sg.outputs.app_db_production]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
  tags = {
    Application = "db"
    Environment = "production"
    Platform    = "app"
  }
}
```

This was working perfectly in Terraform 11. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a change in the AWS provider rather than in Terraform CLI.

Specifically, [the `aws_kms_secret` data source is deprecated](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/guides/version-2-upgrade.html#data-source-aws_kms_secret) and available only (with a deprecation warning) in Terraform 0.11.

To proceed, you must migrate to the newer `aws_kms_secrets` data source. The above link is to the full documentation on that migration, but the relevant part for the purpose of this question is that the outputs for this new data source are in an object attribute named `plaintext`, with the intent that you can then use that entire map as a single value if you need to, in addition to extracting individual values as you were before.

```
master_password = data.aws_kms_secrets.app_db_production.plaintext["master_password"]
```